# Which of the following are true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I need to find which of the following are true?

1. $\exists A\in M_{2\times 5}(\mathbb{R})\ni\dim$ of null space of $A$ is $2$

My ans: False as $\dim Null(A)+\dim Im(A)=5\Rightarrow\dim Im(A)=5-2=3(\Leftrightarrow)$

2. $\exists A\in M_{2\times 5}(\mathbb{R})\ni\dim$ of null space of $A$ is $0$

My ans: False as $\dim Null(A)+\dim Im(A)=5\Rightarrow\dim Im(A)=5-0=5(\Leftrightarrow)$

3. $\exists A\in M_{2\times 5}(\mathbb{R}),\exists B\in M_{5\times 2}(\mathbb{R})\ni AB=I_2$

my ans: True. suppose, $T_1(x_1,\dots,x_5)=(x_1,x_2)$ and $T_2(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,x_2,0,0,0)$ then the matrix of $T_1$ is $A$ and matrix of $T_2$ is $B$ say. $AB$ is $I_2$ which I have calculated.

4. $\exists A\in M_{2\times 5}(\mathbb{R})$ whose null space is $\{(x_1,\dots,x_5):x_1=x_2,x_3=x_4=x_5\}$

I have no idea about this one.

Thanks for correcting me and hlping.

Comment: Please don't make the title all math, it prevents people from right clicking to open in a new tab which is how many of us browse this site.

Comment: I have never seen $\ni$ used for "such that". Many people use $:$ or $\mid$ (most commonly in set notation: $\left\{ a+2 : 1 \leq a \leq 3 \right\}$ or $\left\{ a+2 \mid 1 \leq a \leq 3 \right\}$). I personally use the thorn-with-stroke ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_with_stroke ) for "such that" myself, but I am not aware of anyone else using it.

Comment: @darijgrinberg See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols). I really dislike it because it's unnecessary and it can be confused with set membership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct.

In the third one, I think it is a degree of complexity simpler to just take $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=A^T$-

For the fourth one find a basis of the given subspace, find its dimension and compare to a previous question.

Comment: $(c,c,d,d,d)=c(1,1,0,0,0)+d(0,0,1,1,1)$ so kernel is $2$ dimensional, so impossibleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee. am I right git guddddddddddddd?

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeess.

Comment: thuuuuuuuuuuuuuuunxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Nnnpppppppppppppp.